# Google Chrome saving page as background

Tags: google-chrome

I am having a strange problem. On my Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit desktop machine, the Google Chrome, which is the latest version, is always saving the recently opened page as semitransparent background of desktop and sometimes not of desktop, but of the Google Chrome background. Often updating the system solves the problem but it occurs again.

How to solve ?

[image]

Comment: Could you add screenshots?

Comment: I don't know why the uploaded picture is not prominent. Trying more.

Comment: Looking at the image, are you saying your recent opened page in Chrome is totally black?  Can you use AU as a recent visited page and show us how your desktop background looks after that page?

Comment: I have changed the picture. Now it is showing some page in the background. Though no browser is open and the state is just after restart.

Comment: Isn't this just a [screen burn-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in#Plasma.2C_LCD_and_OLED_displays)? Does it fade away slowly?

Comment: I don't think that it fades away because this problem is there for a couple of months

Comment: @cosmicraga Well of course it burns in again when you use Chrome – try having some other (distinctive) window open for some hours without starting the screen saver or taking off the screen and check whether it changes.

Comment: Sure. But the background page keeps on changing.

Comment: Does it persist when you change the actual background image?

Comment: yes it persists